# Where does connect_to_database() comes from?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/sqlite3/

I get this:
NameError: global name 'connect_to_database' is not defined

Can't really se where it should be defined either?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At a glance, I assume you're supposed to write it yourself, doing whatever you need to do to get a db connection.

At its simplest, this would just be:

```
def connect_to_database():
    return sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
```

Comment: To add: I came across this because of the same reason: I saw this at the same url above, and assumed it was an imported/provided function.  Documentation isn't clear on that point.